# What is the Umbraco 8 equivalent of the Umbraco 7 class ImageCropData?

Tags: c#, umbraco7, umbraco8

In Umbraco 7 there is a class called `ImageCropData`, which is in the `Umbraco.Web.Models` namespace. I am duplicating some objects from an Umbraco 7 site into a version 8 site but `ImageCropData` doesn't appear to exist any more. Does anyone know what the v8 equivalent would be?

Answer (score 2):

`ImageCropperValue` in `Umbraco.Core.PropertyEditors.ValueConverters`